# Как отключить профессиональное освещение на youtube?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

На ютубе появилась функция "профессиональное освещение". Проблема в том что она по умолчанию включена и ее нужно вручную все время отключать при этом из-за нее видео в браузере firefox становится в разрешении 360p.

Я хочу написать скрипт с помощью tampermonkey который будет ее выключать.Но по какой-то причине не срабатывает. В строке @match  я указал  https://www.youtube.com/watch* потому что скрипт должен срабатывать только на странице самими роликами

Вот код:

````
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match      https://www.youtube.com/watch*
// @icon         data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    var osf = document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-menuitem"); //нахожу чек бокс с освещением

    osf[0].setAttribute("aria-checked" , false); //вырубаю его
    

})(); ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данный вами код не работает, ведь `aria-checked` не влияет на работу внутренних скриптов(см. [ARIA](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA)), поэтому давайте разберем другой подход:

Элемент с профессиональным освещением находится под ID "cinematics". Благодаря устройству YouTube, применить `document.getElementById("cinematics").hidden = true` или `document.getElementById("cinematics").style.display = none` можно лишь при единожды, но придётся ожидать появления этого самого элемента, что, в зависимости от скорости ПК(мой, например, подгружает этот элемент далеко не сразу), может занять длительное время и лишний код.

Достаточно лишь вставить кастомный `<style>` с необходимым стилем в любой момент(TamperMonkey позаботится об этом, но разработчику расширения нельзя добавлять этот код в тайминг `document_start`):

```js
var style = document.createElement("style");
style.innerText = "#cinematics{display:none!important;}";
document.head.appendChild(style);
```

Comment: Похоже сработало. Большое спасибо. Единственное ползунок остался на месте но само освещение перестало мозолить глаза.